# input value undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser

I want to show an error message when text box is empty on submit, but is not working and everytime I try to get the value through the console area returns undefined.

CSS

```
<style>
    #error_alert {
        visibility: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #F00;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
    }

    label,
    input,
    button {
        display: block;
        margin: 2px;
    }
</style>
```

Javascript

```
    <script>
    function validate() {
        var inputName = document.getElementsByName("fName")
        if (inputName.value == " ") {
            document.getElementById("error_alert").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Html

```
<body>
    <h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p id="error_alert">invalid name</p>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fName" />
    <label>e-mail:</label>
    <input type="email">
    <button onClick="validate()" type="button">Enviar</button>
</body>
```

PS: When I added `x == null ||` as an opntion on the condition the message would turn visible everytime even when i had something written in the textarea.

Comment: [`getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns an array-like object, not a single element.

Comment: @Teemu Correct.. @OP also `" "` is not blank condition but `""` this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its `getElementsByName` so you are getting list of DOM element`s`, you need to select the particular one out of list.

```js
function validate() {
        var inputName = document.getElementsByName("fName")[0];
        if (inputName.value == "") {
            document.getElementById("error_alert").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
```

```css
 #error_alert {
        visibility: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #F00;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px;
    }

    label,
    input,
    button {
        display: block;
        margin: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Titulo</h1>
    <p id="error_alert">invalid name</p>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fName" />
    <label>e-mail:</label>
    <input type="email">
    <button onClick="validate()" type="button">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName()` returns an array, so your comparison to `" "` is invalid. It would be easier if you add an id to your input as well, then you can use `getElementById()` instead. It returns a single value that you can then compare with as you are.

```
<input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" />

var inputName = document.getElementById("fName");
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
if (inputName.value == " ") {
```

To:

```
if (inputName.value[0] == "") {
```

Answer (score 3):

```
When you use document.getElementsByName, it returns an array, hence input.value will not work.

Try the following -
function validate() {
   var inputName = document.getElementsByName("fName")
        if (inputName[0].value == "") {
            document.getElementById("error_alert").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
}
```